# Handling multipart/form-data in express with cloud functions in 2022

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-platform, multipartform-data

How to handle multipart/form-data req in express backend with google cloud functions in 2022? Researching this issue has taken a lot of my time with no result. I have tries multiple ways and they work fine locally but not when deployed.

**All of the following code works locally but not when deployed**

**Errors are always the same**

- Unexpected end of form when deployed
- Busboy is not a constructor which when I fix with removing the **new Busboy** gives the former error

```
// // // Processing multipart/form-data files middleware

// // const busboy = require("busboy"); // for parsing multipart/form-data
// // const path = require("path");
// // const fs = require("fs");
// // const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");

// // const processFileMiddleware = asyncHandler((req, res, next) => {
// //   const busboyInstance = busboy({ headers: req.headers });

// //   busboyInstance.on("file", async (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
// //     console.log(filename);
// //     // this logs the following:

// //     const filepath = "./uploads/" + await filename.filename;
// //     console.log(filepath)
// //     const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);

// //     file.pipe(writeStream);

// //     file.on("end", () => {
// //         // console.log("File [" + fieldname + "] Finished");
// //         req.file = { originalFilename: filename, filepath };
// //         next();
// //         }
// //     );
// //   });

// //   busboyInstance.on("finish", () => {
// //     console.log("Done parsing form!");
// //     next();
// //   });

// //   req.pipe(busboyInstance);
// // });

// // module.exports = { processFileMiddleware };

// const path = require('path');
// const os = require('os');
// const fs = require('fs');

// // Node.js doesn't have a built-in multipart/form-data parsing library.
// // Instead, we can use the 'busboy' library from NPM to parse these requests.
// const Busboy = require('busboy');

// const processFileMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
//   if (req.method !== 'POST') {
//     // Return a "method not allowed" error
//     return res.status(405).end();
//   }

//   console.log('Processing file...');
//   const busboy = Busboy({headers: req.headers});
//   const tmpdir = "./uploads/";

//   // This object will accumulate all the fields, keyed by their name
//   const fields = {};

//   // This object will accumulate all the uploaded files, keyed by their name.
//   const uploads = {};

//   const fileWrites = [];

//   // This code will process each file uploaded.
//   busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, {filename, encoding}) => {
//     // Note: os.tmpdir() points to an in-memory file system on GCF
//     // Thus, any files in it must fit in the instance's memory.
//     console.log(`Processed file ${filename}`);
//     const filepath = path.join(tmpdir, filename);
//     uploads['file'] = filepath;

//         console.log(filepath)
//     const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);
//     file.pipe(writeStream);

//     // File was processed by Busboy; wait for it to be written.
//     // Note: GCF may not persist saved files across invocations.
//     // Persistent files must be kept in other locations
//     // (such as Cloud Storage buckets).
//     const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//       file.on('end', () => {
//         writeStream.end();
//       });
//       writeStream.on('finish', resolve);
//       writeStream.on('error', reject);
//     });
//     fileWrites.push(promise);
//   });

//   // Triggered once all uploaded files are processed by Busboy.
//   // We still need to wait for the disk writes (saves) to complete.
//   busboy.on('finish', async () => {
//     await Promise.all(fileWrites);

//     /**
//      * TODO(developer): Process saved files here
//      */
//     for (const file in uploads) {
//       fs.unlinkSync(uploads[file]);
//     }
//     res.send();
//   });

// //   busboy.end(req.body);

// console.log(req.body)

//     // The raw bytes of the upload will be in req.rawBody. Send it to
//     // Busboy, and get a callback when it's finished.
//     busboy.pipe(req.rawBody);

//     res.send();

// process incoming request
// upload the file to the bucket

// const Busboy = require("busboy");
// const path = require("path");
// const os = require("os");
// const fs = require("fs");
// const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
// const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
// const { uploadFile } = require("../cloudstorage/uploadFile");
// const random = (() => {
//   const buf = Buffer.alloc(16);
//   return () => randomFileSync(buf).toString("hex");
// })();

// const processFileMiddleware = asyncHandler((req, res, next) => {
//   if (req.method !== "POST") {
//     // Return a "method not allowed" error
//     return res.status(405).end();
//   }

//   console.log("Processing file...");

//   const bb = Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
//   bb.on("file", async (name, file, { filename }) => {
//     const saveTo = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
//     file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
//     console.log(`File ${filename} saved to ${saveTo}`);

//     try {
//       await uploadFile(file, filename);
//     } catch (err) {
//       console.log(err);
//     }
//   });
//   bb.on("finish", () => {
//     //   res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
//     next();
//   });

//   // console.log(Object.keys(req), bb);
//  // docs say this is needed

//   req.pipe(bb);

//   req.on("end", () => {
//     console.log("Done parsing form!");
//     next();
//   });
// });

// module.exports = { processFileMiddleware };

const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");

const processFileMiddleware = asyncHandler((req, res) => {
  const BusBoy = require("busboy");
  const path = require("path");
  const os = require("os");
  const fs = require("fs");
  const uuid = require("uuid");
  

  const busboy = BusBoy({ headers: req.headers });


  let imageToBeUploaded = {};
  let imageFileName;
  // String for image token
  let generatedToken = uuid.v4();

  busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    console.log(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype);
    if (mimetype !== "image/jpeg" && mimetype !== "image/png") {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Wrong file type submitted" });
    }
    // my.image.png => ['my', 'image', 'png']
    const imageExtension = filename.split(".")[filename.split(".").length - 1];
    // 32756238461724837.png
    imageFileName = `${Math.round(
      Math.random() * 1000000000000
    ).toString()}.${imageExtension}`;
    const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), imageFileName);
    imageToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype };
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
  });
  busboy.on("finish", () => {
    admin
      .storage()
      .bucket()
      .upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
        resumable: false,
        metadata: {
          metadata: {
            contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype,
            //Generate token to be appended to imageUrl
            firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: generatedToken,
          },
        },
      });
  });
  busboy.end(req.rawBody);
});

module.exports = { processFileMiddleware };
```

How do the real professionals handle this? I am looking for any insight.

## edit 1
The error

```
node:events:505 throw er;
 // Unhandled 'error' event ^ Error: Unexpected end of form at Multipart._final (functions/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:588:17) at callFinal (node:internal/streams/writable:695:27) at prefinish 
(node:internal/streams/writable:724:7) at finishMaybe 
(node:internal/streams/writable:734:5) at Multipart.Writable.end 
(node:internal/streams/writable:632:5)
```

The frontend which is sending the req has the following code:

```
const API_URL = "http://192.168.1.2:4000/api/admissionForm/submit";
const uploadFile = async (file: any) => {
  const token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user") || "{}").token;
  console.log(Object.keys(file))
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        
      },
    };
    const res = await axios.post(API_URL, file, config);
    return res.data;
  } catch (err: any) {
    if (err.response.status === 500) {
      console.log("There was a problem with the server");
    } else {
      console.log(err.response.data.msg);
    }
  }
};
```

The html part

```
<form onSubmit={handleUpload}>
<input
              type="file"
              className=""
              id="inputFile01"
              style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name={"file"}
            />
<button type="submit">
              Upload 
            </button>
</form>
```

`changeHandler()` code

```
const changeHandler = (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
    const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
    let selectedList = target.files as FileList;
    console.log(selectedList);
    let selected = selectedList[0] as File;

    setFile(selected);
  };

  const handleUpload = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(file);
    if (file) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", file);
      try {
        const res = await uploadFile(formData);
        console.log(res);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  };
```

Some research shows that this is a Cloud functions issue but those research are from 2-3 years old and some of those threads tells me that this is fixed now. Please show me how. I am asking this question in Oct 2022.

Comment: Does this `const filepath = "./uploads/" + await filename.filename;`  point to a directory that exists and where you have write permission when running in the cloud? Also, what's with the `await` in `await filename.filename`?

Comment: @jfriend00 I admit that was a wrong approach, but when I changed that to use tmp directory in the google according to their docs, it still gives the error `Unexpected end of form`

Comment: I'd also suggest you add logging for the `error` event on the `writeStream` and the `file` stream and the `busboyInstance`.  That may shed some light on where things are going wrong.

Comment: ``` node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Unexpected end of form
    at Multipart._final (functions/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:588:17)
    at callFinal (node:internal/streams/writable:695:27)
    at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:724:7)
    at finishMaybe (node:internal/streams/writable:734:5)
    at Multipart.Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:632:5) ``` @jfriend00

Comment: What's creating this request?  Are you 100% sure it's valid `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: @jfriend00 I added the frontend code which is requesting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248771/discussion-between-somebody-coding-and-jfriend00).

Comment: In your `uploadFile()` call, what is the `file` argument?  Where does it come from?  If you don't manually set `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",` in `uploadFile()` what does `axios.post()` naturally set the content-type to?  I'm wondering if `axios.post()` is actually sending something other than `multipart/form-data`, but you're overriding the content-type and messing things up?

Comment: @jfriend00 added the full code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase Functions are built on top of the [`functions-framework-nodejs`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs) package (or at least, an internal variant of the same code), where it [parses the body for you](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/78ba5c1b287e1efbb2f48672b667547eeb1de165/src/server.ts#L91-L95) before your code even [gets the chance to execute](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/78ba5c1b287e1efbb2f48672b667547eeb1de165/src/server.ts#L136-L142). This behaviour is [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request).

This means that when you try to feed `busboy` the request's body stream, it has already been drained - resulting in your "Unexpected end of form" error message. To process the original body of the request, you need to access it via the `rawBody` property added to the request by the framework.

This means that you need to swap out

```
busboy.end(req.body);
```

for

```
busboy.end(req.rawBody);
```

Comment: Hey sam, The code that is not commented is the current code and it is still giving the error. I have already swapped req.body for `req.rawBody`. But I think your explanation makes sense and I am trying it right now keeping in mind that it is already parsed. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Hey Sam, Thanks for this answer man, it works like a charm. The docs you provided gave me the answer and it was so straightforward and simple. I learned something new. Keep up the good work. Thanks again!

Comment: @somebodycoding, what was your specific solution? I'm having the same problem, but req.rawBody did not resolve it. 
Thanks!

Comment: @agentcurry I recommend asking your own question with the relevant code so we can see what's going on.